# Error in UseMethod("select") : no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Tags: r, dplyr

I've tried this before and it worked, but somehow when I try again to use the `dplyr` library it always fails to display data using the `select` command. can anyone provide feedback?

```
  Manufaktur `Layar(inci)` `Harga(Dollar)`
   <chr>              <dbl>           <dbl>

     1 Sharp                 46             736
     2 Samsung               52            1150
     3 Samsung               46             895
     4 Sony                  40             625
     5 Sharp                 42             773
     6 Samsung               46             961
     7 Samsung               40             686
     8 Sharp                 37             574
     9 Sharp                 46            1000
    10 Sony                  40             722
```

and when I want to display data from the table with `select(tv$'Layar(inci)')`, an error like this appears : `Error in UseMethod("select") :no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

Answer (score 2):

`select` expects a data.frame/tibble (based on `?select`)

> .data
> A data frame, data frame extension (e.g. a tibble), or a lazy data frame (e.g. from dbplyr or dtplyr).

and not a vector (`tv$'Layar(inci)'`

```
library(dplyr)
tv %>%
    dplyr::select(`Layar(inci)`)
```

---

using the reproducible example

```
data(iris)
dplyr::select(iris$Petal.Length)
Error in UseMethod("select") : 
  no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

When used with correct syntax

```
iris %>%
   dplyr::select(Petal.Length) %>%
   head
  Petal.Length
1          1.4
2          1.4
3          1.3
4          1.5
5          1.4
6          1.7
```